# How to evaluate global methods and fields when debugging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cil

By CIL editing, people can add methods and fields that don't belong to any class or namespace.

In an assembly, there is a class `internal class <Module>`, which contains all of these globals.
It is possible to view these methods codes and fields by using IL tools (Mono.Cecil, dnlib), or decompile tools (dnSpy).

Is there any way to evaluate or view the value in debugging in Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to just have a `public static class Globals` and store all your globals there.

Then, in all of your files, you do `using static Globals`. (if `Globals` exists in a namespace, you have to use it's full name). The `using static <ClassName>` let's you use all the static fields and methods without having to specify the class, making it seem like they either belong to the current class, or like they are globals, for example:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public int GlobalInt { get; set; } = 42;
    public int GlobalMethod() => 42;
}
```

Without `using static`:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Globals.GlobalInt);
    Console.WriteLine(Globals.GlobalMethod);
}
```

With `using static`:

```
using static Globals;

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GlobalInt);
    Console.WriteLine(Globals.GlobalMethod);
}
```

That being said, it is generally considered bad practice to use global variables  (hence why C# doesn't have them) as any class can change the value of it and it's easy to loose track. Global constants, global readonlys, or global properties with private setters are all fine, however.

Comment: The question is about evaluate code of a IL modified assembly.

Comment: Do you mean "evaluating code"? Besides that, why do you want to do this, what are you trying to do?